Que hace este codigo Javascript del Service Worker?
el código que ven a continuación lo genera automáticamente PWA Builder en un archivo llamado service_worker.js para crear una pwa de una web.
// Fatch resources
self.addEventListener("fetch",e=>{
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(response=>{
      return response||fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});

No me queda claro que es lo que realmente hace este código, ademas, al usarlo y luego usar por ejemplo $_SESSION comienza a tener comportamientos extraños que hacen que no tome los javascripts que vienen a continuación, como si cacheara los archivos sin leerlos mas, excepto haciendo un ctrl+F5. Quisiera que alguien me explique si este código es importante y si lo es como hacer para combinarlo con otros javascripts que existen en mi web.
Gracias
Este es el service_worker.js completo:
// Cached core static resources 
self.addEventListener("install",e=>{
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open("static").then(cache=>{
      return cache.addAll(["./",'./img/misc/logo.webp']);
    })
  );
});

// Fatch resources
self.addEventListener("fetch",e=>{
  e.respondWith(
    caches.match(e.request).then(response=>{
      return response||fetch(e.request);
    })
  );
});


Existen 3 requisitos básicos para una PWA:

Contexto seguro (que utilice HTTPS)
Archivo manifest.json correctamente configurado (muchos de los casos de que la aplicación no se pueda instalar, se debe a que el archivo contiene fallas, o falta algo, o falta algún archivo descrito ahí)
Services Worker que tenga algún mecanismo mismo para la operación offline

Esto último, es lo que tú tienes:
self.addEventListener("fetch",e=>{ //Intercepta TODAS las peticiones al servidor
  e.respondWith( //En lugar de hacer la petición entrega "otra cosa" como respueta (lo que viene abajo)
    caches.match(e.request).then(response=>{ //pregunta si esa petición está en caché (de no estar, esto entrega undefined)
      return response||fetch(e.request); // si existe en caché, entrega lo que tenga almacendado, en caso contrario realiza el fetch
    })
  );
});

Básicamente lo que hace es interceptar la petición al servidor y pregunta si está o no en caché. En caso de estar en caché lo entrega desde ahí, y en caso contrario realiza la petición.
Existen versiones más complejas de lo mismo, por ejemplo, Blazor (hasta .net 7) agrega lo siguiente:


self.importScripts('./service-worker-assets.js'); //este es un archivo que contiene una lista de archivos estaticos (html, css, js, imagenes,etc)
self.addEventListener('install', event => event.waitUntil(onInstall(event)));
self.addEventListener('activate', event => event.waitUntil(onActivate(event)));
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => event.respondWith(onFetch(event)));

const cacheNamePrefix = 'offline-cache-';
const cacheName = `${cacheNamePrefix}${self.assetsManifest.version}`;
const offlineAssetsInclude = [ /\.dll$/, /\.pdb$/, /\.wasm/, /\.html/, /\.js$/, /\.json$/, /\.css$/, /\.woff$/, /\.png$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.gif$/, /\.ico$/, /\.blat$/, /\.dat$/ ];
const offlineAssetsExclude = [ /^service-worker\.js$/ ];

async function onInstall(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Install');

    // Fetch and cache all matching items from the assets manifest
    const assetsRequests = self.assetsManifest.assets
        .filter(asset => offlineAssetsInclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .filter(asset => !offlineAssetsExclude.some(pattern => pattern.test(asset.url)))
        .map(asset => new Request(asset.url, { integrity: asset.hash, cache: 'no-cache' }));
    await caches.open(cacheName).then(cache => cache.addAll(assetsRequests));
}

async function onActivate(event) {
    console.info('Service worker: Activate');

    // Delete unused caches
    const cacheKeys = await caches.keys();
    await Promise.all(cacheKeys
        .filter(key => key.startsWith(cacheNamePrefix) && key !== cacheName)
        .map(key => caches.delete(key)));
}

async function onFetch(event) {
    let cachedResponse = null;
    if (event.request.method === 'GET') {
        // For all navigation requests, try to serve index.html from cache
        // If you need some URLs to be server-rendered, edit the following check to exclude those URLs
        const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate';

        const request = shouldServeIndexHtml ? 'index.html' : event.request;
        const cache = await caches.open(cacheName);
        cachedResponse = await cache.match(request);
    }

    return cachedResponse || fetch(event.request);
}




En mi experiencia, las PWA tienen el problema actualizar el caché, hay veces que ni el ctrl + F5  funciona, y lo que se debe hacer es: F12  -> Pestaña aplicación -> almacentamiento -> botón "Borrar datos del sitio"
Otro aspecto a considerar es que el borrado de caché solo se activa para la próxima que se entré a la aplicación.
Lo que yo hago, es almacenar la versión de la aplicación en el localstorage y además tengo un endpoint en mi API que entrega la versión. Antes que inicie la aplicación comparo que sean iguales, de lo contrario borró todo el caché y hago un reload a la página:
const result = await fetch("/API/Info/GetVer");
const ActualVersion = await result.text();
console.log("Versión: ", ActualVersion)

if (getInstalledVerison() != ActualVersion) {
    const cacheKeys = await caches.keys();
    cacheKeys.forEach(key => caches.delete(key));
    localStorage.setItem("ver", ActualVersion);
    location.reload();
}
else{
  //iniciar la APP
}


Con respecto a combinarlo con javascript, me parece una mala idea. Primero porque es un Services Worker, que es la alternativa a hilos que tiene javascript, por lo que el código dispuesto ahí no se comunica directamente con los script del hilo principal, debes implementar un sistema de mensajería.
Y digamos que efectivamente tu necesitas código en un services worker, en ese casó te creas uno y ya, para que ensuciar este que tiene su propósito definido
